# how to download NordVPN over a filtered internet on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, vpn, update-manager

I'm trying to install nordvpn on my ubuntu 20.04 based on the official [tutorials](https://nordvpn.com/download/linux/).

I downloaded the `.deb` file and installed it using `sudo apt-get install ./nordvpn-release_1.0.0_all.deb`.

I checked `sudo nano nordvpn.list` in this directory:`/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, it contained:

```
#
# NordVPN releases, stable
#
deb https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable main
```

Now when I try to update packages using `sudo apt-get  update` my computer cannot download the nordvpn packages. this is the output:

> sudo apt-get  update Hit:1 http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu focal
> InRelease                                        Hit:2
> http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
> Hit:3 http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
> Hit:4 http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
> Hit:5 http://ubuntu.turhost.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
> Err:6 https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian stable InRelease
> Could not connect to repo.nordvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection
> timed out Reading package lists... Done                     W: Failed
> to fetch
> https://repo.nordvpn.com/deb/nordvpn/debian/dists/stable/InRelease
> Could not connect to repo.nordvpn.com:443 (10.10.34.35), connection
> timed out W: Some index files failed to download. They have been
> ignored, or old ones used instead.

I believe this is due to the filtered internet of mine.

any ideas on how to download NordVPN over a filtered internet?

Comment: has very poor reviews on the Ubuntu Software Center. Have you seen [this reference](https://techshielder.com/how-to-setup-nordvpn-on-ubuntu) on installation?

Comment: This is a question for Nord VPN how do you know there even is a new version?

Comment: `apt-get` will download & install (the 'get' means it downloads) so your description of downloading then installing from a downloaded file makes no sense; `apt` can install a local file you've already downloaded; `apt-get` does not.

Comment: @24601 in the 5th step, it run the `update` command which will gives the error mentioned in the question

Comment: @david the update command is needed to download the required files for installing it

Comment: @guiverc it will install the NordVPN repository as it is instructed in the nordvpn tutorial.

Comment: @codlord best answer so far. I have tried nordvpn on my android phone and it worked just fine, but when I try with this method, it never connects. Wanted to try the software for checking

Comment: you ignored my question how do you know there is a new version?

Comment: @David Pardon me, I don't know it. Please give a name or link